# printing two different loops on the same line

Tags: java, printing

hello everyone I can't figure out how to print these two statements on the same line.

```
   for(int index = 1; index < word.length(); index++){   
        System.out.printf("\n%s", builder.charAt(index));
    }

    for(int index = word.length()-2; index >= 0; index--){
        System.out.printf("\n%s%s",space ,backWards.charAt(index));
    }
```

my objective is to give this method a word and it prints the rectangle, for example:
word = java
it will print:
java
a  v
v  a
avaj

please try to keep it as simple as possible because I'm still a beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to print string vertically, is to loop through it's characters and print one of them on each line

```
String str = "JAVA";
System.out.println(str);
for(int i=1; i<str.length()-1; i++){
    System.out.print(str.charAt(i));
    for(int j=1; j<str.length()-1; j++){
        System.out.print(' ');
    }
    System.out.println(str.charAt(str.length()-1-i));
}
for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++){
    System.out.print(str.charAt(str.length()-1-i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
            String word = "java";
            // print first line
            System.out.println(word);
            String spaces = getSpacesFor(word.length() - 2);
            // print out middle lines
            for(int i = 1; i < word.length() - 1; i ++) {
                // first character is from the normal word order
                String s = "" + word.charAt(i);
                // add middle spaces
                s += spaces;
                // add last character which is backwards order
                s += word.charAt(word.length() - i - 1);
                // print out
                System.out.println(s);
            }

            // print backwards word
            for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i ++) {
                System.out.print(word.charAt(word.length() - i - 1));
            }
```

`getSpacesFor` would be a method like:

```
public static String getSpacesFor(int num) {
    String s = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i ++) {
        s += " ";
    }

    return s;
}
```